# Javascript inheritance with several layers: A->B->C, use functions from A in C

Tags: javascript, inheritance, virtual-inheritance

In javascript I want to achieve the following:

Class A (Array) -> Class B (EntityContainer) -> Class C (EntityList)

In Code:

```
function EntityContainer() {
    ...
}

EntityContainer.prototype = new Array;
EntityContainer.prototype.constructor = EntityContainer;
EntityContainer.prototype.parent = Array.prototype

function EntityList() {
    ...
}

EntityList.prototype = new EntityContainer;
EntityList.prototype.constructor = EntityList;
EntityList.prototype.parent = EntityContainer.prototype
```

Of course, the inheritance stuff could be encapsulated in a "inheritsFrom" function.

Is this the right way to achieve that I could call "this[i]" within EntityList when iterating over all elements (using this.length)?

Is there anything you can do better here?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you would want to do what you describe, is type checking using `instanceof` operator. If you don't need that, you'd be better of with composition, and an array object as instance variable. The `[]` accessor is negligible and can be replaced with `get()`.

Comment: Yes, but basically I did not want to extend the javascript standard array object with my own methods (like contains() etc.). This is why I chose inheritance...

Comment: That depends what platforms do you target, JS 1.6 (ECMA 5th) is already very common, and for instance `a.contains` is easily done with https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some . If you target platforms that don't have these methods, I suggest using shims/polyfills http://www.calormen.com/polyfill/#polyfill meanwhile.